# Array generated by loops

Tags: recursion, list-manipulation

I have an issue making an array by *for*. The idea is to generate the diagonal of the array by a progression, and then replicate that value for the lower part of the array. The part that makes the diagonal works just fine, but the part that replicate the diagonal value for the lower part of the array messed up at column n-2 (it's always the n-2 column that fails). At this point I'm at lost of what is failing.

Here is the code:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
n=6;
V=Array[v,n+1,0];
v[0]=0;

A=Array[a, {n, n}];
For[i=1,i<=n,i++,
    a[i,i]=V[[i+1]];
    For[j=1, j<=i,j++,
        a[i,i]=Append[{a[i, i]}, j*p+V[[1+i-j]]]; 
    ];
    if[i<n, A[[i + 1 ;; n, i]] = a[i, i]]; 
]
MatrixForm[A]
```

Any feedback is welcome, ty

Comment: `if` is not a Mathematica command; use `If`. Moreover it is unclear to me what you want. Probably you mix up `a[i,j]` and `A[[i,j]]`. Only the latter indexes into an array.

Comment: To add onto what @HenrikSchumacher said unless it's inside `Compile` using `For` is probably not the best way to approach your problem

Comment: Yeah, `Do` is in many ways more robust, faster, and more concise than `For`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I changed the `If`, but the strange behavior persist. there is no issue with the `a[i,j]` and `A[[i,j]]` , if that were the case it would fail at every iteration not just at the n-2.